# Showing that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ is the unique positive generator of $(a) \cap (b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ideals

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. $l>0$ is the unique positive generator of the ideal $(a) \cap (b)$. Show that $l = \frac{ab}{d}$ where $d = gcd(a, b)$. I am stuck on this problem. $(a)=\{na: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$...

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Do you know any of the standard elementary number theory results like Bezout's theorem?

Comment: Yes I know au+bv=1

Comment: How do I use that identity for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Show that $l \in (a) \cap (b)$.

**Hint 2:** Show that no proper divisor of $l$ can be in $(a) \cap (b)$.

Comment: $(a) = \{ka: k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $(b) = \{lb: l \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ Then what is the intersection?

Comment: @Jack $$(a) \cap (b) = \{z | \exists k,l \mbox{ such that } z =ka=lb \}$$

Comment: l was a bad choice but I think hint 1 is clear from that, (since a|l and b|l are the properties I am given, so l=xa and l=yb). I am given if a|m and b|m then l|m but not sure about hint 2, Do I need bezout's identity anywhere/?

Comment: @Jack For 2 try to write $a=da_1, b=db_1$, with gcd $(a_1,b_1)=1$. Now if $a|k, b|k$ show that $a_1, b_1|\frac{k}{d}$ and they are relatively prime. What does this mean?